# making an absolute url referencing a local image

Tags: html, image, jsp, url

How do I to make an absolute URL that refers an image into my root repertory app ?

I've tried this using `/projetForum/WebContent/images/angry.gif` as URL but it doesn't work.

```
str = str.replace(":D", "<img src=\"/projetForum/WebContent/images/angry.gif\" title=\"heureux\" alt=\"heureux\" />");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly is `:D` angry? In any way, please elaborate "doesn't work" in developer's terms instead of in enduser's terms. How exactly are you displaying this HTML to the enduser? Did the browser download the image (check HTTP network monitor)? If you're absolutely positive that the URL is right (i.e. it works when you paste that URL straight in browser's address bar), then one probable cause would be that the string value is simply been HTML-escaped. JSF does that as part of builtin prevention against XSS attacks.

Comment: @BalusC, it's just an example, this str will be placed into a JSP. The Browser haven't found the targeted image.

Comment: In other words, the browser retrieved a HTTP 404 error response? Well, then it just means that the URL is wrong. What is the full URL in browser address bar when you try to manually download the image by entering its URL in browser address bar yourself? Once we know that, then we should be able to substitute exactly that URL in the HTML code.

Comment: Yes, the browser retrieved a HTTP 404 error response. I don't know how to find that URL, but, the tree of my application is `projetForum/WebContent/images/angry.gif` when I try to enter `http://localhost:8080/projetForum/WebContent/images/angry.gif` I've got a HTTP 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking closer at the URL which you attempted to use, the presence of `/WebContent` folder is suspicious. This is recognizable as default web content folder name of a typical Eclipse web project. This in turn suggests that you actually used a local disk file system path relative to the IDE workspace root folder in the `<img src>` and somehow expected that it represents a valid URL.

This is wrong. It's the webbrowser who has got to download the image by a valid URL once it encounters the `<img>` element while parsing the obtained HTML output. It's *not* the webserver who has got to magically inline the image's content based on local disk file system path or so. That's not how HTML works.

Provided that the webapp's context root is `projectForum` (and thus the whole webapp is available on `http://localhost:8080/projectForum/`), then the image should be available on the following URL `http://localhost:8080/projectForum/images/angry.gif`. Try it in your browser's address bar first.

Once you found out the right URL, then you should substitute exactly that absolute/relative path in the image's URL so that the generated HTML output ends up like this:

```html
<img src="/projectForum/images/angry.gif" />
```

By the way, the smiley `:D` does not look like angry to me.